# My normal fonts have been changed to hollowed fonts as well as narrow fonts

Tags: windows-10, fonts

[image]
Hey all, my win10 laptop has suddenly transformed the fonts on some pages to not only a hollowed out font, but also the rest of the text is narrower.

For comparison, this is what the narrow text should look like. Notice how it's wider than the first image. [image]

I did sfc /scannow and it said everything was fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you recently installed any fonts? Sometimes they conflict. I have had this happen before.

Comment: @NiallJones Yes I have, I installed the Neo Sans font family from a free website.

Comment: @RegisteredUset Uninstall this and restart your computer. Then let me know if this worked.

Comment: @NiallJones still does it. https://i.imgur.com/p0kdkZU.png